# What can be the smallest Procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create Procedure/Function without Parameters.

```
create or replace procedure p_newname ()
iS
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('ok');
end p_newname;
/
```

But, i am getting the following error message:

"Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors."

Actually i wanted to call this Procedure using - Standalone Execution but without any involvement of parameters be it Formal parameters or Actual parameters:

```
EXECUTE p_newname();
```

Expected result should be - ok

Comment: Your second line should be `AS` not `iS`

Comment: no that's not the problem @daShier

Comment: @daShier - both `AS` and `IS` are allowed.

Comment: Thanks @jarvis. I didn't know about `IS`, and the non-standard capitalization threw me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, you need to remove parentheses after procedure name if procedure doesn't have any parameter during the creation.

But,you can call either by

```
SQL> exec  p_newname();
/
```

or

```
SQL> exec  p_newname;
/
```

or

```
SQL> begin
  p_newname;
end;
/
```

or

```
SQL> begin
  p_newname();
end;
/
```

of course without forgetting to issue

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
```

before them the results to be able to be printed on the screen.

Comment: @Oracle_UNIX_Aspirant it's just below of the downvote arrow :)

Comment: Also if using the SQL [`call`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CALL.html) syntax, parentheses are always required.

Comment: I am unable to tag - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389306/code-formatting-for-cursor-with-parameter-is-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 1):

As the question is

> What can be the smallest Procedure?

and if it means "use as few letters as possible", then something like this might be the answer:

```
SQL> create procedure p as begin null; end;
  2  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Comment: `create procedure p as begin p; end;` is even *shorter* - but it takes longer time to finish;)

Comment: I am unable to tag - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389306/code-formatting-for-cursor-with-parameter-is-not-working-as-expected